# Exception when initializing new PlatformClient()

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am using the jar provided by intuit (ipp-java-devkit-2.0.11-jar-with-dependencies.jar) and having some difficulty. I am able to create my PlatformSessionContext so I know that it is not completely broken. When calling new PlatformClient() I get the following exception:

```
16:29:58,204 ERROR [[requestHandlerBlueDot]] Servlet.service() for servlet requestHandlerBlueDot threw exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
    at com.intuit.platform.util.LoggerImpl.getLogger(LoggerImpl.java:48)
    at com.intuit.platform.util.LoggerImpl.getInstance(LoggerImpl.java:32)
    at com.intuit.platform.client.PlatformClient.<clinit>(PlatformClient.java:52)
    at com.jt.quickbooks.BlueDotMenuServlet.doGet(BlueDotMenuServlet.java:66)
```

Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Issue was that the slf4j logging jars were newer versions and incompatible with what I already have running on my server. Found a (jBoss) deployment error that I didn't notice before:

16:27:26,172 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is incompatible with this binding.
16:27:26,173 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5 or earlier.
16:27:26,173 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version 1.6.x. or 2.0.x

Fix was to remove ipp-java-devkit-2.0.11-jar-with-dependencies.jar and replace with ipp-java-devkit-2.0.11.jar then add a couple jars for the missing dependencies.
The jars I needed to add were:
org.apache.felix.bundlerepository-1.0.3.jar for xmlpull.v1.xmlpullparser, xmlpull.v1.xmlserializer, kdom.Document
signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar for OAuth stuff

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me. Can you please try the following.

```
final PlatformSessionContext context = getPlatformContext(accesstoken,
        accessstokensecret, realmID, dataSource);

PlatformClient client = new PlatformClient();

System.out.println("User's email " + client.getUserInfo(context).getEmail());
```

JavaDoc Ref - http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV2Doc/ipp-java-devkit-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT-javadoc/
(com.intuit.platform.client.PlatformClient)

Please let me know if it works for you.

```
import com.intuit.platform.client.PlatformClient;
import com.intuit.platform.client.PlatformServiceType;
import com.intuit.platform.client.PlatformSessionContext;
import com.intuit.platform.client.security.OAuthCredentials;


public class Test {

    String accesstoken = "keys ****";
    String accessstokensecret = "keys ****";
    String realmID = "*********";
    String dataSource = "QBD";

    String appToken = "keys ****";
    String oauth_consumer_key = "keys ****";
    String oauth_consumer_secret = "keys ****";

    Test(){
        final PlatformSessionContext context = getPlatformContext(accesstoken,
                accessstokensecret, realmID, dataSource);
        System.out.println(context);
        PlatformClient client = new PlatformClient();
        System.out.println("User's email " + client.getUserInfo(context).getEmail());
    }

    public PlatformSessionContext getPlatformContext(final String accessToken,
            final String accessTokenSecret, final String realmID,
            final String dataSource) {

        PlatformServiceType serviceType;
        if (dataSource.equalsIgnoreCase("QBO")) {
            serviceType = PlatformServiceType.QBO;
        } else {
            serviceType = PlatformServiceType.QBD;
        }

        final OAuthCredentials oauthcredentials = new OAuthCredentials(
                oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret,
                accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

        final PlatformSessionContext context = new PlatformSessionContext(
                oauthcredentials, appToken, serviceType, realmID);

        return context;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Test test = new Test();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Adding logging did nothing. As you can see from the stack trace above, the code does not get past "new PlatformClient()".

Comment: Can you share that piece of code where you are getting this exception. I'll try to re-create this.

Comment: Yes I have both in my classpath but are both really required?

Comment: Here is the code:
    final PlatformSessionContext context = webutils.getPlatformContext(accesstoken, accessstokensecret, realmID);
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  try {
   PlatformClient pClient = new PlatformClient();
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   List<String> menuList = pClient.getAppMenu(context);
   if (menuList != null) {
    for (String mItem : menuList) {
     sb.append(mItem);
     out.println(mItem);
    }
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   _log.error("Exception in BlueDotMenuServlet " + e.getMessage());
  }

Comment: sorry. by mistake my last comment got deleted. I'm adding a standalone code in my original post. Loggerfactory is getting initialized all the time. I'm not able to reproduce this scenario. Can you please try with the standalone pgm with your oauth keys.
Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: That worked. It didn't solve my problem but got me to take a deeper look and find the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your menuproxy url is correct. That can create this issue.
Reference:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0020_connect/0010_from_within_your_app/add_the_connect_button

Comment: I believe it is right. menuproxy points to my servlet which handles getting the blue dot menu. Is this correct?